# Geometry Nodes - Reversing splines depending on distance or radius of start and end points

Tags: geometry-nodes, splines

I have tree object constructed with multiple splines. I'd like to make sure the end point of each spline is always the point facing outwards from the center of the tree. I'd like to do this by either comparing the radii of the start and end points of each spline, or comparing the distance of the points to the origin of the tree.

How would I solve this in geometry nodes?

*Here the end points of the splines are scaled up. I want the point outlined in blue to be reversed in this case.*
[image]

Comment: sounds more like you want to compare the direction than the radius or distance